# rank() over in hive

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, hive

I'm converting a SQL Server stored procedure to HiveQL.

How can I convert something like:

```
SELECT 
    p.FirstName, p.LastName,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a.PostalCode) AS Rank
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? You should be able to do the same query in Hive, there is a `rank` UDF in Hive which should behave the same way.

Comment: oh, there is a rank UDF? How can I use it then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Have seen this use case a few times, there is a way to do something similar to `RANK()` in Hive using a UDF.

There are basically a few steps:

- Partition the data into groups with `DISTRIBUTE BY`
- Order the data in each group with `SORT BY`

There is actually [a nice article on the topic](http://www.edwardcapriolo.com/roller/edwardcapriolo/entry/doing_rank_with_hive), and you can also find some code from Edward Capriolo [here](https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/hive-rank).

Here is an example query doing a rank in Hive:

```
ADD JAR p-rank-demo.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION p_rank AS 'demo.PsuedoRank';

SELECT
 category,country,product,sales,rank
FROM (
 SELECT
   category,country,product,sales,
   p_rank(category, country) rank
 FROM (
   SELECT
     category,country,product,
     sales
   FROM p_rank_demo
   DISTRIBUTE BY
     category,country
   SORT BY
     category,country,sales desc) t1) t2
WHERE rank <= 3
```

Which does the equivalent of the following query in MySQL:

```
SELECT
 category,country,product,sales,rank
FROM (
 SELECT
   category,country,product, sales,
   rank() over (PARTITION BY category, country ORDER BY sales DESC) rank
 FROM p_rank_demo) t
WHERE rank <= 3
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes across this question, Hive now supports rank() and other analytics functions.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Answer (score 0):

No big deal 
Somehow in Hive 0.13.1 that comma does not work :-(

so I got it working without the comma

(PARTITION BY category  country ORDER BY sales DESC)