# How to generate the sequence number with hive ql

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

How to write the hive sql to get the table B from table A (without any UDF) ?

### table A

```
PLATFORM    USER_ID CLICK_TIME  CLICK_URL
```

WEB 12332321    2013-03-21 13:48:31.324 /home/

WEB 12332321    2013-03-21 13:48:32.954 /selectcat/er/

WEB 12332321    2013-03-21 13:48:46.365 /er/viewad/12.html

WEB 12332321    2013-03-21 13:48:53.651 /er/viewad/13.html

WEB 12332321    2013-03-21 13:49:13.435 /er/viewad/24.html

WEB 12332321    2013-03-21 13:49:35.876 /selectcat/che/

WEB 12332321    2013-03-21 13:49:56.398 /che/viewad/93.html

WEB 12332321    2013-03-21 13:50:03.143 /che/viewad/10.html

WEB 12332321    2013-03-21 13:50:34.265 /home/

WAP 32483923    2013-03-21 23:58:41.123 /m/home/

WAP 32483923    2013-03-21 23:59:16.123 /m/selectcat/fang/

WAP 32483923    2013-03-21 23:59:45.123 /m/fang/33.html
......

### table B

PLATFORM    USER_ID SEQ FROM_URL    TO_URL

WEB 12332321    1   NULL    /home/

WEB 12332321    2   /home/  /selectcat/er/

WEB 12332321    3   /selectcat/er/  /er/viewad/12.html

WEB 12332321    4   /er/viewad/12.html  /er/viewad/13.html

WEB 12332321    5   /er/viewad/13.html  /er/viewad/24.html

WEB 12332321    6   /er/viewad/24.html  /selectcat/che/

WEB 12332321    7   /selectcat/che/ /che/viewad/93.html

WEB 12332321    8   /che/viewad/93.html /che/viewad/10.html

WEB 12332321    9   /che/viewad/10.html /home/

WAP 32483923    1   NULL    /m/home/

WAP 32483923    2   /m/home/    /m/selectcat/fang/

WAP 32483923    3   /m/selectcat/fang/  /m/fang/33.html

WAP 32483923    4   /m/fang/33.html /m/fang/54.html

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: hadoop-1.4.0 and hive-0.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Rank() without UDF is impossible for now. You can use PIG or use pseudo UDF. Here is similar post ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219969/rank-over-in-hive)). GL!

Comment: thanks, but i can't use any UDF, need to do this by "pure hive sql",any other comments?